# Can not ssh into openshift

Tags: ssh, openshift

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS , trying to ssh login into my openshift gear. But It's not working, no error/success notice showing up after ssh command.

I have tried it by `ssh *login-keys*` as instructed in my openshift account. When execute this command `rhc sshkey list` , I got this

> `default (type: ssh-rsa)
>   -----------------------   Fingerprint: **some fingerprint **   Available:   true
>
> You have 1 SSH keys associated with your account. `

What can I

Answer (score 0):

Try running the rhc setup command, it's possible that the wrong public key got added somehow, or maybe from another computer you added another key?  You need a public key for each private key that you are using (usually a different one on each computer)